# Make WPF MahApps MetroWindow non-draggable

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I've just started using MahApps with WPF. After converting my WPF Window to a MetroWindow it's no more locked. With standard WPF and the following settings 
`WindowStyle="None"  ResizeMode="NoResize` the window is not movable.

However with MetroWindow it is movable. I don't want users to be able to move the window around. How can I achieve this with MetroWindow?

Comment: There is a `IsWindowDraggable` property for `MetroWindow`

Comment: Post your answer Mathew ;) 

For future problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219933/mathew) said, you can set **`IsWindowDraggable`** property of your `MetroWindow` to **`false`**. A sample code can be like this:

```
<controls:MetroWindow 
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.Window1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"

             IsWindowDraggable="False"
             ResizeMode="NoResize"
             WindowStyle="None"
             ShowTitleBar="False"
             >

             .....

</controls:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: Just accepting it for others as @Mathew's comment was on time but he didn't post an answer.